# How do I efficiently create API mocks for isolated testing of each microservice?

Tags: mocking, automated-tests, testng, microservices

We have an app with more than a dozen Rest-based microservices using Spring boot. I want to create automated tests to test each of my services in isolation while mocking producer service APIs. I tried creating mocks using wiremock, but it is so tedious to create these API requests and responses for mocks manually. Is there a better way to implement service tests?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, API mocking is tedious effort but very impactful to help test for functional and integration earlier in the development cycle. So, I think your goal is very apt.

You already are trying to use Wiremock. Like you said, it requires developers to create and maintain mocks so that they don’t become stale. Here are a couple of approaches than can reduce the pain of creating and maintaining API mocks.

a) if you can point the egress URLs in your service to a proxy such as nginx, Envoy and then forward them to your producer services you can create these API mocks in an automated way. At the proxy, you may be able to log the egress requests to your producer services and their responses. You could then create mocks out of the logged requests and responses. Even [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) and [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) also have proxies that you might be able to use with additional configuration/setup effort.

b) [Mesh Dynamics](https://www.meshdynamics.io/) is a tool that enables this use case of efficiently creating service tests quite well. It saves the ingress and egress requests/responses along with the ingress-egress tracing so it helps with debugging. It then converts them to service tests, and the mocks are automatically created from the captures. You can run the service tests locally or in the CI pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking will always be tedious and from my experience you always need to weigh the added benefit with the cost of development. That said I see 3 ways forward based on the limited description. The first as you already said, using wiremock, can be tricky but once you get the hang of it gets easier.

Second option could be mocking the interfaces communicating with the other services. I'm a c# guy so in my case it would be moq but I believe there might be some tools for java that do th same thing, https://site.mockito.org/ ?

The third option is to actually build a dummyservice with httplistneners generating a wanted response. Might sound overkill but won't necessarily mean more work. And can be quite easy to spin up automatically.